# Order / Order lines, want to get order total but multiple lines are inflating

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I trying to write a report and I've tried a number of approaches, my issue is the way the data needs to be grouped is really complicating the query.  See my attached query, which is the closest I've gotten.  I wrote another query which I think would work, but after executing for 20 minutes I killed it.   Here's the query:

```
SELECT right(EV.Name, (Len(EV.Name) - ABS(Charindex('-',EV.Name )))) AS [Store Name],
    sum(OLI.Quantity) as [Total Packages], sum(OPUI.TaxAmount) as [Total Tax],
    sum(OPUI.ShippingAmount) as [Total Shipping], sum(OPUI.OrderTotal) as [Order Total],
    sum(PP.Cost) as [Total Cost],
    sum(case when OLI.PackageID = 11 then 1 else 0 end) AS [Package 1],
    sum(case when OLI.PackageID = 12 then 1 else 0 end) AS [Package 2],
    sum(case when OLI.PackageID = 13 then 1 else 0 end) AS [Gift Package],
    sum(case when OLI.PackageID = 15 then 1 else 0 end) AS [Digital Download],
    sum(case when OLI.PackageID = 16 then 1 else 0 end) AS [Magnets],
    sum(case when OLI.PackageID = 17 then 1 else 0 end) AS [Mugs],
    sum(case when OLI.PackageID = 20 then 1 else 0 end) AS [Puzzles],
    sum(case when OLI.PackageID = 18 then 1 else 0 end) AS [3.5x5 Cards],
    sum(case when OLI.PackageID = 19 then 1 else 0 end) AS [5x7 Cards],
    sum(case when OLI.PackageID = 14 then 1 else 0 end) AS [4x8 Cards],
    sum(case when OLI.PackageID = 50 then 1 else 0 end) AS [Postcards]
FROM OrderPUInfo OPUI
    INNER JOIN Orders ORD ON ORD.OrderID = OPUI.OrderID
    INNER JOIN OrderPULineItems OLI ON OLI.OrderID = ORD.OrderID
    INNER JOIN PUConsumerData CD ON CD.ConsumerDataID = OPUI.ConsumerDataID
    INNER JOIN PUEvents EV ON EV.EventID = CD.EventID
    INNER JOIN PUPackages PP ON PP.PackageID = OLI.PackageID
WHERE CONVERT(date,ORD.OrderDate) <= '2013-12-24' AND CONVERT(date,ORD.OrderDate) > '2013-11-08' AND
    EV.EventID > 3914 and EV.EventId < 3977 and EV.TourID = 283
GROUP BY EV.Name
ORDER BY EV.Name
```

I'm sure you can see the problem...  the Order Total gets inflated when there are more than OrderPULineItems for a given order.   My thought was to do outer applys for the different packages, but that never returned a result, the query just spun until it would timeout.  Then I tried do a subquery for the totals, but again, because the subquery is almost the whole query again without line items, it too a long while for the execution.

Som of the gurus here have helped in the past with simple optimizations that make what I originally wrote sing, so I'm hoping that you all can help again.

Comment: if you provide schema and expected results, then someone could help you

Comment: There's a couple of approaches you can take like `SUM() OVER()` or inline views however without sample data it's a bit difficult to see exactly what you're looking for. Also you should probably tell us what RDMS you're using since not all the SQL features are universally supported.